# How to compare two dates in two cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, date, comparison, formula

How do I compare two dates (if they're the same date) in two different cells in Excel?

e.g.:
Cell A1: 11/12/2018
Cell A2: 11/12/2018

If they match return "YES", otherwise "No".

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(A1)=NUMBERVALUE(A2),"YES","NO")
```

I tried the above but to no avail.

Comment: Do you get an error or the wrong output?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I get: #VALUE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the two dates have a time componant to them.

Try:

```
=IF(INT(A1)=INT(A2),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: This does seem to work, and yeah I think it has the time associated too.

Comment: Now, how would I check IF A1 = A2 OR A1 is NOT more than 1 day than A2?

Comment: Look into AND().  Try to make it work, if you get stuck come back and ask a new question.

Comment: Cool, do you have any idea on how to check if a date is equal to the date plus 1 day?

I'm trying to do something like: 
=IF(OR(INT(A1)=INT(A2), A1=A2+1),"YES","NO")

i.e check if A1 is equal to A2 OR A1 is NOT more than 1 day from A2

Comment: wrap dates in INT again just like the other part.

Comment: So if the date in A2 is one more day than the date in A1, arithmetically it's +1 ?

So if I were to INT(*date*) - 2 that would translate to 2 days before?

Comment: To excel dates are numbers that are formatted as dates.  The number is the number of days from 1/1/1900.  So 1 day = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can easily get confused if **A1** contains a genuine date or a date/time formatted as a date and **A2** contains a text value.

First insert the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function txet(r As Range) As String
    txet = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(r.Text)
End Function
```

Then pick a cell and enter the formula:

```
=IF(txet(A1)=txet(A2),"YES","NO")
```

[image]